# Run Symfony 1.4 using PHP built in server

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-1.4

I have a old symfony 1.4 project to upgrade in my current company. I have a complex situation. I am not able to install a local server ( Apache ) in my system. Not able to create another environment in client system also ( MNCs always sucks. Even need permission from client to change my Netbeans theme ).

So I thought about running the code in PHP built in server. Luckily I have PHP v5.6.25 installed in my system where code available. Also I know, only symfony v2.6 or above support  'server:run' method. I could run PHP built in server using the command PHP -S localhost:8000 in my system.

My question is, is there any way I can use the PHP built in server to run Symfony 1.4 project in my system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i recommend a vagrant or docker for running it.

Comment: As long as you are in the `web` directory, you should be able to run `php -s site_name:8000`. We are currently doing that for a old project as well

Comment: @fucethebads: Installing something is not ideal solution in my case. Sorry.....

Comment: @jc1arke : I have already tried it. But end up with some fatal errors: failed opening required files in autoload file. Any idea about this situation.

Comment: If you are _tasked_ with upgrading this Symfony app, your company should provide the necessary means to do so. Otherwise they are just setting you up to fail. I suggest to talk to your superior about it.

Comment: @Nightfox maybe update the question with the fatal errors listed from the terminal/web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Try first to run your server in another files with just a Hello World. If this works, it should works in web/app directory. For your error with autoload watch your composer